# Symfony Fails opening my sfDoctrineDatabase.class.php

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, autoload, include-path

My problem is very simple, yet I feel lost while looking at it ...
I am currently working on a Symfony project located on an SVN repository.

It has worked well all day but suddenly it crashed...

Now I cant launch any page of my site. They all return me the same error message

```
Fatal error: sfAutoload::require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prjAnnuaire/trunk/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineDatabase.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/home/ar3s/ProjetAnnuaire/prjAnnuaire/trunk/plugins/sfPhpExcelPlugin/config/../lib/PHPExcel') in /home/ar3s/ProjetAnnuaire/prjAnnuaire/trunk/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfAutoload.class.php on line 165
```

If anyone has any idea, I am all ears ...

Comment: I think I have a clue, an apple fan boy also working on the project uploaded is configuration file, now the project seems to look for MAMP on my Linux machine ...

(if I were a troll, I'd say that it is another proof that Apple tries to take over the world with very mean means ...)

Comment: I still dont get where the problem came from (yet I am still convinced that it has something to do with my evil apple using co-worker) but I "rm -rf"-ed my project dir, did another "svn update", a "php symfony cc" and an appropriate chmod, now it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"symfony cc" fixed this for me.

Comment: I had the same problem after replacing my project to an other location. thx